# Проблема с Ajax в IE 11

Tags: javascript, json

Сделал Ajax запрос, вот такой

```
$.ajax({
          type: 'get',
          async: false,
          cache: false,
          dataType : 'json',
          url: '/videos/by_video_id?video_id=' + i,
          success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            var where_is_liner = where_is_place.find('.liner-line')
                  .append('<div class="box blocks" data-id="'+ (i+1) +'">' +
                            '<iframe width="294" height="163"'+
                              'src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/'+ data['data']['video_id'] +'" ' +
                              'frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen=""> '+
                            '</iframe>' +
                          '</div>')
              }
        })
```

Но он не работает в IE 11,как быть? И можно ли как-то такой запрос переписать на Post

Comment: Почему вы решили, что не работает?

Comment: Проверил,выдает ошибку SCRIPT7002.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14527387/script7002-xmlhttprequest-network-error-0x2ef3-could-not-complete-the-operati – часто помогает гуглить саму ошибку

Comment: К,сожалению,ничего из этого не помогло...